# Mocking cookies with responses

Tags: python-requests, python-responses

I have a piece of code that deals with cookies being set by the server as a response of an HTTP response. I'm attempting to test it using `responses`, like so:

```
responses.add(responses.GET, "http://invalid/cookies",
              adding_headers = {
                  "Set-Cookie": "foo=bar; " +
                                "domain=.invalid; " +
                                "expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; " +
                                "path=/; " +
                                "HttpOnly",
              })
```

I would then expect this to return my cookie, but no such luck.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('http://invalid/cookies')
session.cookies['foo'] # KeyError
```

Indeed, this works outside of the context of `responses.activate`:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set?foo=bar')
session.cookies['foo'] # 'bar'
```

How can I mock cookies with `responses`?

Comment: I see this is actually tested-for in responses ([#](https://github.com/getsentry/responses/blob/dc0578d208289e8a8471a9356f91e85acf6c7c03/test_responses.py#L309)), so my version of the library might just be outdated...

Answer (score 2):

The `python3-responses` package in Ubuntu 16.04 is out of date. You will need to use a newer version from `pip`/`pip3`, after which this behaviour works as expected.

Do note however that this, too, is buggy at the time of writing:

```
responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://invalid/cookies',
             adding_headers = {
                  "set-cookie": "foo=bar; " +
                                "domain=.invalid; " +
                                # "expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; " +
                                "path=/; " +
                                "" # "HttpOnly",
              })
session = requests.Session()
session.get('http://invalid/cookies')
dict(response.cookies) # this should have one cookie
{'foo': 'bar', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.invalid'}
```

Comment: I have lifted the contents of the set-cookie header straight from stackoverflow.com...